# My project icon is not display on AVD screen

Tags: android, icons, android-virtual-device

If i'm correct, when we run our android project from eclipse, AVD will run and then our project icon app will be displayed on AVD's screen.

But, i don;t know why, since somedays ago, when i run my project, there is no icon of my project displaye on AVD screen.

What's the problem? thanks

Comment: Add a screen shot of avd

Comment: @Metalhead1247 : my avd is just nexus s , it looklike usual android phone.

Comment: @lkmhr : it just simple hello world activity like usual, no other component there

Comment: You must have deleted the ic-launcher.png icon from drawble

Comment: @Metalhead1247 : i will try it, for information: my eclipse adt works fine on windows xp, but always got that problem when running on windows 8.1 64 bit, strange,

Comment: Doesn't work, deleting ic-launcher no effect,s